# Property of stress-tensor in flat spaces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conservation-laws, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Let $T_{ab}$ be a stress-tensor in a flat space satisfying conservation equations. Define
$$
P^i=\int T^{oi}d^3x, \;\; D^i=\int T^{00}x^id^3x
$$

Can anyone show me how to prove
$$
\frac{dD^i}{dt}=P^i
$$

and
$$
\frac{dP^i}{dt}=0~?
$$

---

Update:

Following is my try:
$$
\frac{dD^i}{dt}=\int\frac{d(T^{00}x^i)}{dt}d^3x=\int\frac{\partial T^{00}}{\partial t}x^id^3x
$$

By conservation law we have
$$
\frac{\partial T^{00}}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial T^{01}}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial T^{02}}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial T^{03}}{\partial z}=0
$$

However, I don't know how to move on...

Comment: @joshphysics, hi, I have updated my post.

Comment: Use the conservation law that you have written and integrate by parts.

Comment: Cross-posted from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/678845/11127